# What is this flying animal that hovers like a hummingbird?

Tags: species-identification, lepidoptera

What is this animal?

[image: the animal]

Characteristics:

- Has a long curved bill.
- Has green upper body and a dark black lower body.
- Likes petunias.
- Hovers like a hummingbird but is a bit smaller.
- Has small rear feather-like tufts and is very odd shaped.
- Moved quickly from flower to flower.

Comment: Yes, that's definitely a duplicate. I'm voting to close.

Comment: Also, I just turned my answer into a *community wiki*, so I don't get any more points for this answer.

Answer (score 7):

That's a lepidopteran insect called *hummingbird moth*.

There are several species of hummingbird moths. Their more distinctive feature, as the name implies, is that they hover just like a hummingbird.

Your photo is not the best one for identification, but it seems to be a [hummingbird hawk-moth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hummingbird_hawk-moth), from the Genus *Macroglossum*, specially because the *rear feather like tufts* (which are just elongated setae).

Here is a better photo, for comparison:

[image]

<sup>*Macroglossum stellatarum*</sup>

However, according to the colors you described, your species is probably different from that in the photo above.

Here is one flying (from a different species):

[image]

Comment: Do you know the typical habitat. I was left puzzled during a visit to Lantau Island, Honk Kong and this looks similar.

Comment: It depends on the exact species.